# Передача переменной между методами контроллера MVC

Tags: php

Ситуация приблизительно такая:
Сайт построен на паттерне mvc.
В контроллере есть два метода:

```
    /**
     * объект предназначенный для сбора верстки
     * @var Views 
     */
    protected $viewer;

    /**
     * объект для работы с данными
     * @var AbstractModel
     */
    protected $model;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->viewer = new Views();
        $this->model = new ModelAuth();
        $this->viewer->template = "auth_template.php";
    }
    public function action_index() {
    ...
    }

    public function action_register() {
    ...
     Router::redirect('auth/');
    }

    /**
     * файл Router 
     */
    static public function redirect($url) {
    header('Location: ' . self::root() . '/' . $url);
    exit();
    }
```

Собственно вопрос) Как передать переменную или массив между action_index() и action_register()? После редиректа обьект создается заново и переменную через свойство передать не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, разумеется. И MVC здесть не при чем. Это основы протокола НТТР. Каждый экшен в контроллере выполняется, обрабатывая свой запрос, и поэтому передавать что-либо из метода в метод абсолютно бессмысленно.

Какое-либо значение можно передать между запросами стандартными способами - либо через БД, либо через сессию, либо через клиента. Все зависит от того, что это за значение и для чего оно нужно.